# Writing a MVC application with Perl CGI

Tags: perl, model-view-controller, cgi

I have a client who wants me to design a new web app from scratch

The problem is that he wants me to use only core modules that come with perl (5.10 or 5.12)

Is there a way to write MVC apps with just CGI?

I know about Catalyst, Mojolicious and Dancer and how easy it is to do MVC with them, but I have no clue on how to do it with CGI alone

Are there any code examples that I could see and inspire from? (I've already googled but didn't find anything that I could use)

Also, like with Mojo and Dancer, is there any way I can generate links (Routes from Mojo, and Rails)  from CGI?

Thanks

Comment: with http://perlbrew.pl/ you can install your own perl and modules

Comment: I thought that with perlbrew you can install different perl versions and may be used for testing apps against those versions (like backwards compatibility), and of course other features. But my question is: how can I write a MVC web-app with only CGI? is it possible? Are there any examples that I can have a look at?

Comment: Ok, thanks..maybe I'll found a way

Answer (score 1):

First off, what's the reason for the "core modules only" restriction?  Does that also mean that you can't write any new modules of your own?  The most effective solution would undoubtedly be to convince the client to let you use CPAN.

If you're allowed to write your own non-core modules, would you be able to get away with including a new module named "Prancer" which looks suspiciously like Dancer?  (i.e., Grab the Dancer source tree and `s/Dancer/Prancer/g` across the whole thing, then add it to your project.)

But, if all else fails... yes, it's possible to at least use MVC principles and strong separation of concerns under CGI.pm, although you won't have an actual framework helping you with it unless you write that framework yourself.  You'll also have to write any database abstraction layer and templating engine yourself, too.  I know this is possible because I was doing it myself 5-10 years ago, back in the Dark Ages before I switched to Dancer.  I can't offer any examples, though, because I've successfully forgotten where I buried those bodies.

Comment: There were some reasons why he is not fond of using CPAN, one of which is that, when the server crashes, it might take to long to reinstall all modules that the web app depends. As far writing from scratch a web app, my skills are not that strong (yet) and it might take too long. I can write modules from scratch but knowing that cpan offers whatever I need ...why do that? Anyway I need to pursue him to accept to work with a framework that already exists. tack sa mycket :)